# Problems Initializing Vungle in android application

Tags: android, vungle-ads

I'm trying to add a video ad to my app. I have a series of problems that I do not know how to solve.

- **Problem 1:** After going through the Vungle tutorial and changing my code to conform to the tutorial, my program would not run. I had a Error of `"multiple dex files define landroid/support/v4...."`. After looking online, I was under the impression that I had to delete the android support file in the library folder as well as the support file that came with Vungle. I did so and my program worked once again.
- **Problem 2:** Once my program was working again I tried using the Vungle videos. When running the Vungle initialization failed. The logcat gave me an error saying I was missing a service in my manifest. This service to be exact:

  ```
  <service android:name="com.vungle.publisher.VungleService" android:exported="false"/>
  ```

I have declared this service in my manifest, however.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: Can you post a bit of your logcat file? The specific error and any surrounding logs could be helpful

Comment: Hello @Craig Nordquist I have the same problem as you do. Did you managed to get it fixed by any chance?